# Browser rendering time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to capture the rendering time for pages, in an automated way.I tried the same using two approaches

a)Create a selenium script, attach httpwatch to the browse window, collect metrics[The free version of httpwatch doesn't give me all the metrics I need ]

b)Use selenium to launch a chrome window, and collect performance logs using the chrome, performance capabilty], and then try to read the content of the log file by loading it back to chrome or some other tool which would suit the purpose. 
the code I used in selenium is

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\IEDriverServer\\chromedriver.exe",desired_capabilities={'loggingPrefs': {'performance': 'ALL'}})
```

The problem is chrome is not able to give me any data when I save the output to a file and load it.

What is it that I am doing wrong, or please let me know if there is a better way to do this. The metrics I need are basically Rendering time on the browse, Rendering start- Onload event start.
I am using python for the selenium scripts